# Find out correct xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have an html page like this:

```
...
<div class="container">
    <div class="title">Meat</div>
    <div class="someclass">
        <div class="tile AAA">
            <div class="text">AAA</div>
            <img class="image" src="somewhat.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="someclass">
        <div class="tile BBB">
            <div class="text">BBB</div>
            <img class="image" src="somewhat.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="title">Fish</div>
    <div class="someclass">
        <div class="tile AAA">
            <div class="text">AAA</div>
            <img class="image" src="somewhat.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="someclass">
        <div class="tile BBB">
            <div class="text">BBB</div>
            <img class="image" src="somewhat.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
...
```

I need to be able to get selenium click an img for a specific element (for example, i want Meat-BBB's img) but I can't find a way to get it by xpath

Any help will be appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

This will click on the Meat-BBB's img:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[.='Meat']/following-sibling::*[2]//img")).click();
```

**It finds the 2nd sibling to the div element having text/innerHtml as "Meat", and then traverses to the first "img" element in it.**

Comment: @Bharath: First of all `//div[.='Meat']` can be also represented by `//div[text()='Meat']` and not `div[@text()='Meat']`.  And **[*2]** means the 2nd sibling immediately following the div having exact innerHtml as "Meat". For your xpath, modifying like this will work for you `//div[text()='Meat']/following-sibling::div[2]/div/img`. Here, `::div[2]` **means the 2nd div element immediatedly following the div having exact innerHtml as "Meat".** I hope this is clear for you.. :)

Answer (score 0):

This will be the xpath for your Meat-BBB's img `/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/img`
You can find xpath of any element by following steps.

```
1. Open your HTML file with any browser 
2. Press F12 and inspect that element by clicking on that element
3. Now right click in html panel on the element and click on Copy XPath
```

Done! Now you have XPath.

Answer (score 0):

To make this Xpath more Generic , we can define a string like

```
// assign the value under which you want to click image Meat or Fish
String classTitle = "Meat";
```

and chage the xpath as follows:

```
//div[.='+classTitle+']/following-sibling::*[2]//img")
```

Answer (score 0):

The xpath will be - yourText
`//div[div[text()='yourText']]/descendant::img`